# How do I fix "attempt to index nil" error

Tags: roblox

I'm creating a game where you collect boxes and deliver them to people. I made a simple prototype but this code doesn't work.

```
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local leaderstats = player.leaderstats
local boxes = leaderstats.boxes

boxes = boxes + 1
    
end)
```

Here when the proximity prompt is triggered, it's supposed to add 1 to the player's boxes. For some reason it doesn't work.

Here's the error:

> attempted to index nil with 'leaderstats'

I tried using FindFirstChild instead of WaitForChild but it didn't work too.